# 4SNS TCBC - Which Mac Pro sensor is that?

Tags: hardware, startup, mac-pro, cpu, temperature

Briefly my Mac Pro (4,1 Early 2009 ) stopped booting which I *eventually* traced to the plastic clip holding the north bridge down failing. Seems to be a common issue.

Replaced the clips and now it will boot again and is stable but refuses to *run* the 2nd CPU. Kernel boot messages show it's there but disabled.

Apple hardware test gives error of 4SNS/1/40000000: TCBC-252:000 which from various sites on the net I understand to mean

```
4SNS - Sensor
TCBC
|----- Temperature
 |---- CPU
  |--- CPU B ?
   |-- C ?`
```

Any idea on the numbers ?

Can anyone help me diagnose here, is it new Heatsink time or new Logic board time. Neither is great but a heatsink is much cheaper than a logic board.Is it something else that's fixable ?

- Both CPUs verified good in socket A.
- All RAM verified good in Socket A RAM slots.
- No diagnostic LEDs lit.
- New thermal paste everywhere
- SMC reset
- PRAM reset

EDIT: RAM Clarification
EDIT: Things done
Thanks

Comment: reset SMC already? [idk the numbers, sorry.] If the clip failed, it might have fried something. New paste everywhere? (wow, that was stream of consciousness, sorry)

Comment: @tetsujin Tried all that. Must have redone the CPUs and paste 5 times by now. As they work in either socket at least I know they're ok. My theory is I damaged the CPU board or heatsink whilst replacing the thermal paste somehow. So want to know what the code actually means.

Answer (score 1):

I rang Apple in the end, they didn't know either without seeing it. 8-)

Suggested I take it in for a free diagnosis.

Before I did that I tried taking the heatsink sensors connected off and replacing it.

Bingo, all fixed.

So the answer must be that this error is the heatsink sensor.